# Rancid can't download Cisco Configuration

Tags: cisco, rancid

Using CentOS 7 with Rancid configured.

I'm using Rancid to get my Cisco switches configuration, but seems that Rancid isn't able to get my configs. The output of my logs:

```
starting: Seg Out 8 18:47:17 WEST 2018

Trying to get all of the configs.
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net: missed cmd(s): all commands
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net: End of run not found
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net: clogin error: Error: Couldn't login
```

My `.cloginrc` file:

```
add user *.net {admin}
add password *.net {PASSWORD_REMOVED} {PASSWORD_REMOVED}
add autoenable *.net            1
add method *.net ssh
add userprompt *.net  {"User Name:"}
```

When I tried to run `/usr/local/rancid/bin/clogin sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net` it looks like the `enable` command is missing:

```
rancid@it-tests logs]$ /usr/local/rancid/bin/clogin sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net
spawn ssh -x -l admin sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net
Password: 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
=============================================================================
==        UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS TO THIS DEVICE IS PROHIBITED!!!              ==
==                                                                         ==
==  You must have explicit, authorized permission to access or configure   ==
==  this device. Unauthorized attempts and actions to access or use of     ==
==  this system may result in civil and/or criminal penalties.             
==  All activities performed on this device are logged and monitored.      ==
=============================================================================
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sw-it-dist-4>
sw-it-dist-4>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

For example, if I run the `clogin` command manually I'm able to see my configuration:

```
[rancid@it-tests rancid]$ /usr/local/rancid/bin/clogin -c "show runn" sw-dc-tor-1.cbr.net.wit
sw-dc-tor-1.cbr.net.wit
spawn ssh -x -l admin sw-dc-tor-1.cbr.net.wit
Password: 

sw-dc-tor-1>enable

Password required, but none set
Password: 
sw-dc-tor-1#
sw-dc-tor-1#terminal length 0
sw-dc-tor-1#terminal width 132
sw-dc-tor-1#show runn
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 10393 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 13:56:17 UTC Thu Sep 27 2018 by admin
! NVRAM config last updated at 13:46:16 UTC Thu Sep 27 2018 by admin
!
version 15.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
(...)
```

But if I run the `/usr/local/rancid/bin/rancid-run` I have this error:

```
[rancid@it-tests logs]$ tailf Switches.20181009.114630 
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 1.
sw-it-tor-1.cbr.net.wit: missed cmd(s): all commands
sw-it-tor-1.cbr.net.wit: End of run not found
sw-it-tor-1.cbr.net.wit clogin error: Error: Couldn't login
!
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 2.
sw-it-tor-1.cbr.net.wit: missed cmd(s): all commands
sw-it-tor-1.cbr.net.wit: End of run not found
sw-it-tor-1.cbr.net.wit clogin error: Error: Couldn't login
!
```

I don't understand what I'm missing...

---

**Edit:**

Thank you for your reply.

I've changed the `autoenable` option, and changed the `hostname` to `.net.wit.`

My `.cloginrc` file:

```
add user *.net.wit {admin}
add password *.net.wit {PASSWORD_REMOVED} {PASSWORD_REMOVED}
add autoenable * 0
add method *.net.wit ssh
add userprompt *.net.wit  {"User Name:"}
```

Now if I run this command `/usr/local/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/rancid/.cloginrc sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit` I have this output:

```
[rancid@it-tests root]$ /usr/local/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/rancid/.cloginrc sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit
spawn ssh -x -l admin sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit
Password: 
-------------------------------------------------------------
===================================
UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS TO THIS DEVICE IS PROHIBITED!!!              
===================================
-------------------------------------------------------------
sw-it-dist-4>enable
Password: 
sw-it-dist-4#
```

But if run the `/usr/local/rancid/bin/rancid-run` in my logs I have this:

```
[rancid@it-tests logs]$ tailf Switches.20181012.112810 
Trying to get all of the configs.
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit: missed cmd(s): all commands
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit: End of run not found
sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit clogin error: Error: Couldn't login
```

What I'm doing wrong this time?

Comment: Welcome.  Are you quite certain the user credentials you're using have sufficiently high privilege?

Comment: Hi @jonathanjo,

yes, this user have full privilege. 

I think the problem is the command enable isn't sent to my swicth.

Comment: @user2968390 Is it a local user or an account on something like RADIUS or TACACS?

Comment: @JesseP. 

Is a local user

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you have `autoenable` switched on in your config, which indicates that the username you're using (`admin`) already has "enable" privilege.  If you have the opposite `autoenable * 0`, RANCID will issue an `enable` command, with the password you've defined.

I believe the reason it behaves differently when you run it by hand on `sw-dc-tor-1.cbr.net.wit` is that this hostname ends in '.wit' and so doesn't match the `*.net` you have in your `.cloginrc` which triggers the `autoenable`.

See http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/man/cloginrc.5.html

Comment: H @ijonathanjo,I've changed the autoenable option, and changed the hostname to .net.wit. Now if I run this command /usr/local/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/rancid/.cloginrc sw-it-dist-4.cbr.net.wit I able to see the executed commands with sucess.

Comment: But if run the /usr/local/rancid/bin/rancid-run in my logs I have the " missed cmd(s): all commands" , " End of run not found" , " clogin error: Error: Couldn't login" errors. What I'm doing wrong?